# Unable to set textLabel in viewForHeaderInSection [UITableView]

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am getting textLabel value from API Successfully. But unable to set in **viewForHeaderInSection**. In my app there are different section at different index, means some time I get two section, some time one and some time three

I am try this Code -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let headerView = HeaderView(tableView: self.tblView, section: section)
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        let subjectNameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 19, y: 4, width: 282, height: 35))

        subjectNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        subjectNameLabel.font = UIFont (name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 16)
        subjectNameLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        headerView.userInteractionEnabled = true

        let dataArrayTblView = dataArrayForTableView
        let subjectNameTxtValue = dataArrayTblView.valueForKey("subjectname")

        subjectNameLabel.text = subjectNameTxtValue as? String
        subjectNameLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 75/255.0, green: 193/255.0, blue: 210/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

        headerView.addSubview(subjectNameLabel)

        return headerView
    }
```

Comment: Show the init method of `HeaderView`.

Comment: in my case i have also get a response from API and after API i set a value for viewForHeaderInSection title .

Comment: in this place `let headerView = HeaderView(tableView: self.tblView, section: section)` use `let headerView = UIVIew()`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik my header view is expandable. See screen shot in my question

Comment: @iDeveloper when you get your response from API at that time did you reload your tableview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try My code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let frame: CGRect = tableView.frame
        let title: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(50, 3, 200, 30))
        title.text = TotalSection[section] as AnyObject! as! String!
        title.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        title.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold",
                            size: 15.0)
        let headerView: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height))
        headerView.addSubview(title)

        headerView.layer.backgroundColor = BUTTON_SUBMIT_LIGHT_BLACK.CGColor
        return headerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
       return 40
}
```

Comment: your `title.text = TotalSection[section] as AnyObject! as! String!
` Working perfect.

Comment: Now i want to set textLabel, getting from API. but it print same value on label(table view cell)

Comment: I am using `cell.titleLabel.text = titleName[indexPath] as AnyObject! as! String! `

Comment: Did you update your array with Your API response ? and after update your array then reload your tableview that viewForHeaderInSection Value change.

Comment: When I `print(titleName)` it print two different value `[0]:Test1 [1]:Test2`. And when i set it on cell it show only `Test1` for all cell on Tableview cell.

Comment: func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return TotalSection.count
       
    }

Comment: My NumberOfsection works perfect. I want to handle my tableviewcell value

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  
  print("You selected cell \(indexPath.item)")

    }

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper code of header in section. You can show the date and set the width according to your text.

/*

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    return self.showHeaderViewController(section)

}

func showHeaderViewController(section: Int) -> UIView {

    // Header View
    let headerView : UIView = UIView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 35))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    headerView.tag = section

    // Set Date on label
    let dateString  =  self.jsondata.objectAtIndex(section).valueForKey("Date") as! String


    //Get the width of String
    var sizeOfString = CGSize()
    if let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14.0)
    {
        let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font] // it says name, but a UIFont works
        sizeOfString = (dateString as NSString).sizeWithAttributes(fontAttributes)
    }

    // Header View Label.
    let headerName = UILabel()
    headerName.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, sizeOfString.width + 20 , 20)
    headerName.center = CGPointMake(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width / 2, CGRectGetHeight(headerView.frame)/2)
    headerName.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 139/255, green: 51/255, blue: 66/255, alpha: 1.0)
    headerName.textAlignment = .Center
    headerName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    headerName.layer.cornerRadius = 7
    headerName.clipsToBounds = true
    headerName.font =  UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14.0)
    headerName.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    headerName.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    headerName.numberOfLines = 0
    headerName.text = finalDate

    headerView.addSubview(headerName)

    return headerView

}
```

Hopefully, this will helps you.

Thanks Mandeep Singh

Comment: can you elaborate your question, so that i can help you proper.